# utm_odometry_node fails to build

Tags: ros, gps-umd, gps-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a fresh checkout of  [gps_common](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=gps_common) , my utm_odometry_node fails to build, citing the error:

`` Linking CXX executable ../bin/utm_odometry_node
CMakeFiles/utm_odometry_node.dir/src/utm_odometry_node.o: In function `ros::serialization::Stream::advance(unsigned int)':
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/include/ros/serialization.h:675: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/include/ros/serialization.h:675: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/include/ros/serialization.h:675: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/include/ros/serialization.h:675: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/include/ros/serialization.h:675: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
CMakeFiles/utm_odometry_node.dir/src/utm_odometry_node.o:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/include/ros/serialization.h:675: more undefined references to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status ``

The issue seems to be that throwStreamOverrun() alone is not defined in serialization.h; it's defined in serialization.cpp. I'm running ROS diamondback on Lucid.

Is there a simple workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10979/utm_odometry_node-fails-to-build/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was an unmet dependency of roscpp_serialization in this package.

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, one of my friends told me I was missing some linker dependencies to ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun().

And also that I needed to add the package that contains ros::serialization to the build_dependencies and the run_dependencies in the package.xml and also to the CMakeLists.txt.

In the CMake-file the build_dependencies are in the line that starts with
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
and the run_dependencies usually are in the
catkin_package( ...
block.
Also, in the line
target_link_libraries(your_executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
that belongs to your executable you might need to add the ${catkin_LIBRARIES} if it is not already there.

For me that worked and hope for you also.

---

Originally posted by [lizyazpin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8651/lizyazpin/) with karma: 1 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1